# how to configure travis to allow me to use nslookup

Tags: php, travis-ci, nslookup

I wrote my own open source library code.

https://github.com/simkimsia/UtilityLib/

I have a function which attempts to get IP address by host.

https://github.com/simkimsia/UtilityLib/blob/master/Lib/HttpLib.php#L34

I wrote a test case for this.

https://github.com/simkimsia/UtilityLib/blob/master/Test/Case/Lib/HttpLibTest.php#L45

It passed in my localhost, but failed in Travis CI.

See https://travis-ci.org/simkimsia/UtilityLib/jobs/8874800

Basically it says nslookup not found.

How should I configure travis to allow me to use nslookup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`nslookup` is not installed by default on the VMs. You can install it by adding this to your `.travis.yml`:

```
before_install:
  - sudo apt-get -qq update
  - sudo apt-get -qq install dnsutils
```

Comment: it works! for confirmation see https://travis-ci.org/simkimsia/UtilityLib/builds/9258813